# Resize LVM partition DomU Windows

Tags: xen, lvm, partition

I have a xen DomU running with Windows Server 2003 on a lvm partition has 10GB but i need more.

if a Linux partition, I would do:

```
# umount
# lvextend -L +10G /dev/<VG>/<LV>
# resize2fs /dev/<VG>/<LV>
```

but the partition has inside a partition ntfs in other words

with kpartx command i can see

```
vg-lv1 :  0 20948697 /dev/vg/lv 63
```

How can resize this?

Comment: Boot a livecd in a VM that supports expanding NTFS partitions?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. You can grow NTFS volumes from within Windows using the [`diskpart`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325590) command. IIRC this does not work for the system volume, though.
2. Since you exposed the partition(s) with `kpartx` you should be able to grow the file system from the Dom0 with something like [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).
3. You can use a Live CD (e.g. [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/)) as mentioned by @Zoredache.

Comment: I'll try with a liveCD if [this](http://www.pyrkosz.pl/KVM_Resize_NTFS_partition_in_LVM_volume.html) fails